# Retrieving a User's Posts and Previous Companies via API

Tags: linkedin-api

I have been reading the LinkedIn API documentation, and have a few questions about what is possible.
It appears to me that the the API has been severely restricted in the ways I was looking to use it. Essentially I was looking to have a rolodex in my app with contacts, for each contact, if they provided their linkedIn info, it would show the authenticated user this other user's last 3 posts and last 3 companies they worked for. Essentially like an extension of the user's contact info in the rolodex.

For the getting the Posts there is the Posts API, however it appears that you can only view and get posts of an organization or the authenticated member, but if I wanted to show the authenticated member the posts of another person based on that other persons LinkedIn profile, that doesn't seem to be possible based on the description of

> r_member_social: (Restricted) Retrieve posts, comments, and likes on behalf of an authenticated member. This is a private permission.

I can't tell if this means its not possible or you need specific permission from LinkedIn to use it?

As for the previous companies the other member worked at, it seems that along with I'm guessing the Posts API full access you need to become a LinkedIn Sponsored Partner. When trying to find information on this though.. I found it a bit lacking.
It appears that the Posts API is part of the marketing package, so I guess I would need that? but I am not sure if that would give me access to a full profile as well?

So I suppose my questions is two-fold:

1. Is what I am attempting to do even possible in the LinkedIn API partner or not.
2. If it requires a partnership, which of the four private API's would I need?